# BizTalk poll typed polling--poll only once a day

Tags: sql-server, biztalk

I'm using biztalk 2010 and have a situation where I need to poll a database table once a day. I will be getting 10 to 100 requests per day.

Right now my table has 3 columns:

1. XMLdata of xml datatype
2. date column
3. Number

Now I need to poll the data once a day and set the status to Completed when it has been polled succcessfully.

Can anyone help me? How do I set this flag in a stored procedure, so that the same data is not polled twice a day?

thanks
Sri

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to give certain records a status for being polled already, you will need to add a 'status' column to this table. When you picked up the records from the database using the stored procedure, you can set the status to 'polled', so your stored procedure would no longer pickup that record anymore.

A possible strategy could be to add a 'Visible' column to the table that has a default value of '1' (bit). Once the data has been picked up (transactionally) by the BizTalk WCF-SQL adapter, you would then set the column to '0'.
Obviously, your stored procedure would only query records with column 'Visible' set to '1'.

If you are in the situation that you cannot change the table itself, you would need to either copy the data into your own, custom, database table or keep a unique identifier (that marks the last polled record) somewhere on your system.

Hope this helps,
Pieter